# Row Transposition Cipher

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to write a program to implement a transposition cipher. When the user provides the key 'TAPE' and the message "HelloworldMessage" my program is only showing only `Hell`, `owor`, `ldMe` and `ssag` and skipping the last "e" from "message," which is wrong. The output should be:

```
Hell
owor
ldMe
ssag
exxx
```

and `xxx` should complete the message before encrypting. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;  // needed for Scanner

public class transpositionCipher
{

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
String key;
String message;
String encryptedMessage; 
// Letters in the x-axis
int x=0; 
// Letters in the y-axis
int y=0; 


// Prompt the user
System.out.print( "Type your Key : " );


// Read a line of text from the user.

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
key = scan.nextLine();

// Display the input back to the user.
System.out.println( "Your Key is " + key );


//Prompt the user
System.out.print( "Type your Message : " );


//Read a line of text from the user.
message = scan.nextLine();

//Display the input back to the user.
System.out.println( "Your Message is " + message );



encryptedMessage = "";

// To set the temp as [x][y]
char temp[][]=new char [key.length()][message.length()];
char msg[] = message.toCharArray();
// To populate the array
x=0;
y=0;
// To convert the message into an array of char
for (int i=0; i< msg.length;i++)
{
temp[x][y]=msg[i];
if (x==(key.length()-1)) 
{
x=0;
y=y+1;
} // Close if 
else 
{
x++;
}
} // Close for loop

// To sort the key
char t[]=new char [key.length()];
t=key.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(t);

for (int j=0;j<y;j++)
{
for (int i=0;i<key.length();i++)
{
System.out.print(temp[i][j]);
}
System.out.println();
}

System.out.println();

// To print out row by row (i.e. y)
for (int j=0;j<y;j++){ 
// To compare the the sorted Key with the key
// For char in the key
for (int i=0;i<key.length();i++){ 
int pos=0;
// To get the position of key.charAt(i) from sorted key
for (pos=0;pos<t.length;pos++){ 
if (key.charAt(i)==t[pos]){ 
// To break the for loop once the key is found
break;
}
}
System.out.print(temp[pos][j]);
encryptedMessage+=temp[pos][j];
}
System.out.println();
}

System.out.println(encryptedMessage);
System.exit(0);
}
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Type your Key : tape
Your Key is tape
Type your Message : HelloworldMessage
Your Message is HelloworldMessage
Hell
owor
ldMe
ssag

lHle
roow
elMd
gsas
lHleroowelMdgsas
```

Comment: Did you encrypt your question?

Comment: please check it again..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally sort this problem on my own.....

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;  // needed for Scanner

public class transpositionCipher
{

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
String key;
String message;
String encryptedMessage; 
// Letters in the x-axis
int x=0; 
// Letters in the y-axis
int y=0; 


// Prompt the user
System.out.print( "Type your Key : " );


// Read a line of text from the user.

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
key = scan.nextLine();

// Display the input back to the user.
System.out.println( "Your Key is " + key );


//Prompt the user
System.out.print( "Type your Message : " );


//Read a line of text from the user.
message = scan.nextLine();

//Display the input back to the user.
System.out.println( "Your Message is " + message );


int msgchar = message.length();
int keycahr = key.length();

if (!((msgchar % keycahr) == 0)){

do{
message = message + "x";
msgchar = message.length();
}while(!((msgchar % keycahr) == 0));

}


encryptedMessage = "";

// To set the temp as [x][y]
char temp[][]=new char [key.length()][message.length()];
char msg[] = message.toCharArray();
// To populate the array
x=0;
y=0;
// To convert the message into an array of char
for (int i=0; i< msg.length;i++)
{
temp[x][y]=msg[i];
if (x==(key.length()-1)) 
{
x=0;
y=y+1;
} // Close if 
else 
{
x++;
}
} // Close for loop

// To sort the key
char t[]=new char [key.length()];
t=key.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(t);

for (int j=0;j<y;j++)
{
for (int i=0;i<key.length();i++)
{
System.out.print(temp[i][j]);
}
System.out.println();
}

System.out.println();

// To print out row by row (i.e. y)
for (int j=0;j<y;j++){ 
// To compare the the sorted Key with the key
// For char in the key
for (int i=0;i<key.length();i++){ 
int pos=0;
// To get the position of key.charAt(i) from sorted key
for (pos=0;pos<t.length;pos++){ 
if (key.charAt(i)==t[pos]){ 
// To break the for loop once the key is found
break;
}
}
System.out.print(temp[pos][j]);
encryptedMessage+=temp[pos][j];
}
System.out.println();
}

System.out.println(encryptedMessage);
System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String args[]) {

```
    System.out.print("Type your Key : ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String key = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Type your Message : ");
    String message = scan.nextLine();
    int msgchar = message.length();
    int l = key.length();

    if (!((msgchar % l) == 0)) {

        do {
            message = message + "x";
            msgchar = message.length();
        } while (!((msgchar % l) == 0));

    }
    String ans = "";

    char temp[][] = new char[key.length()][message.length()];
    char msg[] = message.toCharArray();
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        if (msg[i] == ' ')
            temp[x][y] = '_';
        else
            temp[x][y] = msg[i];
        if (y == (key.length() - 1)) {
            y = 0;
            x = x + 1;
        } else {
            y++;
        }
    }

    char t[] = key.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(t);

    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(temp[j][i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        int pos = find(key, t[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            ans += temp[j][pos];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(ans);
    System.exit(0);
}

private static int find(String key, char c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        if (key.charAt(i) == c) {
            return i;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).